# Using a helper as component attribute

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to be able to assign a string returned by a helper to a components attribute.

Here's what I got that isn't working:

```
{{nav-title text=(translate user.likes name=user.profile.name)}}
```

It tries to find `translate` on the controller (I guess) and throws the following error:

```
Handlebars error: Could not find property 'translate' on object (generated users.user.likes controller).
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that. I'd say either make a new property on whatever context that `nav-title` is being rendered in and do the logic there, or make a new component and move the logic inside.

It's ok to use components for domain-specific stuff. For example this could be a `user-likes-nav` component, which knows how to translate a user's likes before rendering the template.